# Issue with arXiv LaTeX - xypic diagrams rendering badly

Tags: xy-pic, rendering, arxiv

I’m having an odd issue with the arXiv’s LaTeX processing: xypic diagrams that look fine when processed on my own system are rendering badly when processed by the arXiv.  My question is: **Is this simply a consequence of some intended setting in the arXiv’s tex configuration, and if so, does anyone know a workaround?  Or is it a bug, that I should report to them?**

Specifically, in most viewers, xypic diagrams in the arXiv-produced pdfs look somewhat clunky or pixelated:

[image: bad arXiv-produced diagram] (arXiv-processed) vs. [image: good home-baked diagram] (home-processed)

In more complex diagrams, it significantly hurts readability.  At higher magnifications, one can see more precisely what’s happening: the arrow shafts are slightly misaligned (looking at the arrow tips), possibly also with too high a line width, and the dots in a dotted arrow come out as bulky horizontally-aligned squares, rather than better-sized diagonally-aligned squares.

[image]

My home-processed pdf's render fine across various viewers.  The arXiv-produced ones are more inconsistent: the ugliness shows up most consistently in Chrome (on both Mac and Linux), whence the above screenshots; to a fair extent also in Acrobat and on some printers; and to a much lesser degree on the Mac OS Preview system viewer.

The issue can be seen in the wild in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.2851v1), e.g. the second diagram on p.37.  (That paper also shows that diagrams produced in TikZ — many of the more complex diagrams — don’t seem to suffer from the issue.)  MWE for the issue:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\title{MWE for arXiv/xypic issue}

\author{Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine}

\begin{abstract}
Bug testing, not intended for actual arXiv upload.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

So, we need to fill a square
  \[\xymatrix{
  A \ar[r] \ar@{^{(}->}[d]_i & Y \ar[d]^{t} \\
  B \ar[r] \ar@{.>}[ur]     & X
  }\]
but the arrows come out badly!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should make an standalone version of your picture, perhaps as an `.eps`. or an `.pdf`. file and include that file instead generating it on the fly?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdain Please report this to arXiv. Others seem to have the same problem as well. If this issue has been solved by the time, please let us know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Please report this to arXiv. This seems to be a problem on their side as I have heard about that more often. Maybe they just need to update some packages. In the meantime, you could check if `tikz-cd` works better on this site (And maybe for you. Quite easy and more beautiful in case of the hooked arrow).

Here I redid your example in `tikz-cd`:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow{r} \arrow[hook]{d}[swap]{i} & Y \arrow{d}{t} \\
    B \arrow{r} \arrow[dotted]{ur} & X  
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]