# tikz-cd [equal] and arxiv

Tags: tikz-cd, arxiv

I seem to be running into an issue while uploading a TeX file on the arxiv while trying to use `tikz-cd`.

I think arxiv is using an older version of TikZ/pgf which does not support the `[equal]` arrow. I've seen other instances of this question popping up, but the solution always seemed to be "upgrade your TikZ". On my computer it is in fact up to date and no errors appear. But when I try uploading to arxiv the `autotex` will refuse to compile.

Is there a workaround to the `[equal]` arrow in `tikz-cd`?

EDIT: I just noticed that using the option `[-,double]` produces almost the desired effect. Maybe there is a way to tweak that?

Comment: Hi, you should show us a compilable version of your diagram. I do not want to type it in order to tweak around. Maybe together with a screen-shot of your result and the one of arxiv.  As I have heard about such issues several times in the last few weeks, you might think about contacting arxiv and to ask them for an update. I do not know this page, but a polite e-mail request never does harm.

Comment: Of course you could try to redo your diagram with `xy-pic`. But maybe this will just put the problem in relation to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171472 . But give it a try. Most diagrams can easily be translated to the other approach.

Comment: Using [-, double equal sign distance] instead of [equal] works for the arxiv.

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole: thanks, I did not know that.

Comment: arXiv will be rebuilding their TeX environment in the next few months. You might try again when they have rolled out the new build.