# Achieving tikz shift right/left with old version on arXiv

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, arxiv

I have the following diagram using the tikz-cd package:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[]
A  \rar[equal]   & B \\
C  \uar[twoheadleftarrow,shift right=.60ex]
   \uar[hookrightarrow,shift left=.60ex]
\end{tikzcd}
```

This compiles perfectly well on my own computer, but when submitting to the arXiv produces a number of compile errors.

- ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/equal' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
- ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/shift right' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

It seems the source of the problem is that arXiv uses older versions of tikz-cd and pgf, which do not support these keys.

The first error can be worked around by replacing `[equal]` with `[-, double equal sign distance]` (see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196899/tikz-cd-equal-and-arxiv#comment499147_196899)), however I don't know how to achieve the results of the shifts right and left with other commands. Does anybody know another way to achieve the same results, preferably with minimal extra work (i.e. I'd rather avoid translating all my diagrams to `xy-pic` if possible)? Including an updated `tikzlibrarycd.code.tex` with the submission (as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223770)) doesn't work for the reasons specified in that answer.

Comment: Does it work if you copy (only!) the definition of the keys into the preamble ?

Comment: Have you talked to the maintainers of arXiv? I have suggested that on several post around here, but never got an answer. Maybe they are willing to finally update to something newer.

Comment: @percusse: I'm in the process of trying this, but it's leading down a rabbit hole of defining the definitions in the definitions, and so on. I'm not sure if it will terminate before I've copied over the entire library.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: I haven't talked to the maintainers (though I have spoken with a moderator), but I'll try this. I'm not sure how much hope there is that a random person with this issue will convince them to update their system in sufficient time to make a difference for this posting.

Comment: @StephenMorgan I know what you mean, but maybe everybody thinks like this. If you search this site for arXiv, you will find several post complaining about the missing updates of TeX on arXiv. You are not alone... Would be nice, if you get some maintainer informed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the same effect can be achieved in a way the arXiv accepts by substituting `xshift=.60ex` for `shift right=.60ex` and `xshift=-.60ex` for `shift left=.60ex`. This should be instead replaced with `yshift` if the arrows are horizontal. And of course if the arrows are diagonal you need to manually pick your `xshift` and `yshift` values to work well.

It also seems that arXiv has updating to TeXLive 2014 amongst their goals for 2015. This problem should be resolved as soon as they have done so.

Comment: This did not work for me. It removed the error but no shift occurs in my diagram.